# Original Image copied 0 bytes in zip folder using php

Tags: php, php-ziparchive

I have code for 3 types of images copied into zip folder.  1 is thumb , 2 is bigThumb and 3rd is original image. thumb and bigThumb images is working fine but original image copied also into zip folder but with 0 bytes. This functionality is working fine in my local xampp but not working in live server. Pls help me.

This is my code ::

```
$zip = new ziparchive;
if ($zip->open('foldernameofzipfile/tourappTest.zip') === TRUE) 
{
 $zip->addFile("copiedpath/".$nvLastId."_".$neworignalimagename, 'zipfolderpath/'.$nvLastId.'_'.$neworignalimagename);

 $zip->addFile("copiedpath/".$nvLastId."_".$neworignalimagename, 'thumbandzipfolderpath/'.$nvLastId.'_'.$neworignalimagename);

 $zip->addFile("copiedpath/".$nvLastId."_".$neworignalimagename, 'bigThumbandzipfolderpath'.$nvLastId.'_'.$neworignalimagename);
}
$zip->close();
```

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` see if it yields anything.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I tried it but not display any error.

Answer (score 0):

Now solved this question. I just changes in the coding of when i run first time original image then not working but i copied first line and put on end, then working good. So solved the issue.